# How to add a new project to source control in Xcode 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

[image]How do I add a new project to source control (SVN) using Xcode 5?

In "Source Controller" only checkout is clickable and all other are unclickable.

i have existing copy of my project. And i want to upload this app on SVN. how add existing copy to SVN in XCode 5.

As in image you can see all other options are unclickable. i want to add this project to SVN.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: i follow this but i am not find any   Working Copy > New Branch. in it .   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/CreatingaBranchinaRepository/CreatingaBranchinaRepository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013353-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following steps for checkout latest version from SVN server

- Xcode click on checkout button (Source Control -> checkout)
- Enter your repository location and click next
- Select project from project list (Stored on svn server)
- Select location where you want to store project and press checkout
  [image]

Upload existing project to SVN server

- Open terminal and move to your project path
- cd 'Your project path'
- In following comment add server path and execute it
- svn import 'Your Project Path' 'Server path' "Initial Import”

Comment: I got the solution in below link but this will be use full for others. Thanks for your good replay. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should close Xcode, locate your project in the Finder, and create a directory hierarchy appropriated for SVN

```
/projectdir
/projectdir/branches
/projectdir/tags
/projectdir/trunk
```

Then, you should put your Xcode project directory into `trunk`.
Once you've done that, and created your repository on your server using `svnadmin create PATH-TO-PROJECTDIR`, you can import your local copy into the newly created repository on the server. Note that svnadmin doesn't create intermediate directories contained in PATH-TO-PROJECTDIR.
Use `svn import projectdir svn+ssh://your-server-url/your-repository-path -m "First commit"`.
Now you are able to check out your trunk (with Xcode or svn command) and version control in Xcode will be enabled.

Comment: Hi @Ayaz can you please share the solution you got from apple.developer

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/add_repository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH4